# Spark UI showing 0 cores even when setting cores in App

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am having a strange issue with running an application off of the spark master url where the UI is reporting a "STATE" of "WAITING" indefinitely as 0 cores are showing up under the RUNNING APPLICATIONs table no matter what I configure the core count to be.

Ive configured my app with the following settings where spark.max.cores = 2 & spark.default.cores = 2 & memory set to 3GB.  The machine is an enterprise class server with over 24 cores.

```
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName(Properties.getString("SparkAppName"))
            .setMaster(Properties.getString("SparkMasterUrl"))
            .set("spark.executor.memory", Properties.getString("SparkExecMem"))
            .set("spark.cores.max",Properties.getString("SparkCores"))
            .set("spark.driver.memory",Properties.getString("SparkDriverMem"))
            .set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
            .set("spark.deploy.defaultCores",Properties.getString("SparkDefaultCores"));

    //Set Spark context
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(5000));
```

[image]

Spark WebUI states zero cores used and indefinite wait no tasks running.  The application is also using NO MEMORY whatsoever during run time or cores and immediately hits a status of waiting when starting.

```
Spark-defaults.conf 
spark.yarn.max_executor.failures         3
spark.yarn.applicationMaster.waitTries   10
spark.history.kerberos.keytab    none
spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files        False
spark.yarn.submit.file.replication       3
spark.history.kerberos.principal         none
spark.yarn.historyServer.address         {removed}.{removed}.com:18080
spark.yarn.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms       5000
spark.yarn.queue         default
spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads   25
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead         384
spark.history.ui.port    18080
spark.yarn.services      org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryService
spark.yarn.max.executor.failures         3
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions     -Dhdp.version=2.2.6.0-2800
spark.history.provider   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryProvider
spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions    -Dhdp.version=2.2.6.0-2800
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead       384
```

Submit script

`spark-submit --class {removed}.{removed}.{removed}.sentiment.MainApp --deploy-mode client  /path/to/jar`

**EDITED: 2/3/2016**
After running with --master yarn-cluster I am receiving this in the yarn logs error.  I have also included my updated submit configuration

Submit Configuration

```
spark-submit --class com.removed.removed.sentiment.MainApp 
--master yarn-cluster --supervise 
/data04/dev/removed/spark/twitternpi/npi.sentiment-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar 
--jars /usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,/usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/spark/lib/spark-1.2.1.2.2.6.0-2800-yarn-shuffle.jar,/usr/hdp/2.2.6.0-2800/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.2.1.2.2.6.0-2800-hadoop2.6.0.2.2.6.0-2800.jar
```

Error Message

```
   ClassLoaderResolver for class "" gave error on creation : {1}
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: ClassLoaderResolver for class "" gave error on creation : {1}
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.getClassLoaderResolver(NucleusContext.java:1087)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.validatePropertyValue(PersistenceConfiguration.java:797)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.setProperty(PersistenceConfiguration.java:714)
    at org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration.setPersistenceProperties(PersistenceConfiguration.java:693)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:273)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:247)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:225)
```

Comment: I am getting similar error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359801/spark-job-submitted-waiting-taskschedulerimpl-initial-job-not-accepted - Standalone Cluster on AWS EC2 - while submitting PySpark application via Spark Rest API. Any clue how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem when the required memory size for the executor, set by `spark.executor.memory` in `spark-defaults.conf`, is bigger than that on the AWS node. But since you only set 3.0 GB as your memory, I think there might be other causes in your case.

Comment: Same here, but what's the relation between memory and cores allocated?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in yarn, you need to tell your application to use yarn.  Add master yarn-cluster to your spark-submit command

```
spark-submit --class your_class --master yarn-cluster /path/to/jar
```

EDIT:

The spark.cores.max is for Mesos or Standalone.  Try setting this:

.set("spark.executor.cores","2")

And at runtime add this to the submit

--num-executors=2

I am curious though, as it should default to 1 core per executor.  Are the worker nodes registered with the YARN for Spark?  Have you successfully used Spark at all on this cluster in yarn-client or yarn-cluster mode?

Comment: ran it as yarn-client instead still same issue.

Comment: Are the executors running? They are apparently not. Check the logs to see why.

Comment: If I am running as Standalone Cluster on AWS EC2, what changes do I need to make - In my SUBMIT API - I did add num-executors = 2. Still got the same error. @JoeWiden